# Unable to send email with Attachment in Jmeter: Response code:500 Response message:IOException while sending message

Tags: jmeter, smtp, performance-testing, ioexception

I am facing an issue while attaching a file in my SMTP sampler.
Below are the steps performed:
1-Writing the Summary Report results into a file/folder i.e D:/ABC/XYZ${__time(ddMMyyhhmmss)}.csv (It successfully write on that path)
2-Attaching the same file i.e D:/ABC/XYZ${__time(ddMMyyhhmmss)}.csv  in my SMTP sampler against Attach file(s) field.

Now I Execute my Script and got this error.
Response code:500 Response message: IOException while sending message

And after that, when I don't attach any file. My script runs successfully.

One more thing I want to add. Earlier to this script, I was able to send the attachments too but those were from my Gmail account added in SMTP. And now I am doing it from my company's email account i.e. using outlook in SMPT sampler.

Please guide me in resolving the said issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your `${__time(ddMMyyhhmmss)}` will generate different results **each second**:

   [image: ${__time(ddMMyyhhmmss)}.]

   so you most probably need to amend:

   - first usage as `${__time(ddMMyyhhmmss,timestamp)}`, this way the first function call will store the generated value into `timestamp` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
   - second, third, etc. as `${timestamp}`

   [image]
2. [Outlook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Outlook) is an application which can access multiple mailboxes using various protocols like SMTP, POP, IMAP or Microsoft Exchange. JMeter supports first 3, but if your company is using MS Exchange as email transport - you won't be able to use SMTP Sampler, you will have to switch to [JSR223 Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) and write your mail sending code in [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/) using library like [javaxt-exchange](https://www.javaxt.com/documentation/?jar=javaxt-exchange.jar) or [EWS Java API](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api)

Comment: Hi Dmitri, Thanks for the valuable feedback. I tried the solution you have given but the result is the same. And for point no. 2 regarding SMTP, as I have already mentioned that without attachments I am able to send the mail via the company's provided SMTP but with attachments, I am still facing the same problem.